# How to create and keep in sync a local nuget repository with only internally approved packages?

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

per internal policies I have to setup a local nuget repository that contains only the packages approved by internal committee.

I know how to setup a local nuget server and I also found how to download all packages from Nuget (http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/02/downloading-a-local-nuget-repository-with-powershell.aspx), but what I'd need is a way to just download the packages that are approved with their dependencies, save them on my local server and then possibly keep them up do date when a new version comes out and it is "re-approved" internally.

Thank you

Comment: You can use tools like Artifactory to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) was built for :)

ProGet is a private NuGet repository designed to manage both third-party and in-house libraries used as application dependencies. There's a free version of ProGet available that meets most organizational needs.

There are also other private repositories available, including MyGet, JFrog Artifactory, and Sona Nexus. Make sure to check out [Taking NuGet to the Enterprise](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/taking-nuget-to-the-enterprise/) for other best practices in introducing NuGet in your organization.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)

Comment: Too bad the free version doesn't allow specifying the packages to download (from what I see, connector-filter are only in the enterprise version), otherwise would have been good fit.

Comment: Quite an old post, but I'm interested in knowing just how much benefit the noted solutions offer compared to the likes of just building and deploying your own using the likes of the NuGet.Server package for .NET. Using this package (which is humorously a NuGet package itself) you can convert a basic .NET website into a NuGet server site, after providing some specific configuration settings. Then you just deploy it as normal, define the connection to it within Visual Studio and away you go. I've created and deployed NuGet servers within minutes using this approach, but I am a C# guy, after all.

Comment: Regarding the pre-approval aspect: just have your NuGet packages live under version control. That way you will be able to have your packages undergo the likes of sprints and release cycles - all of which can hook into already established processes. Treat your NuGet server packages in a similar fashion as you would any website or web app. Follow your preferred development and review processes, and you should be fine. :)